# swipeEnabled is not working in TabNavigator for swipe disable

Tags: ios, react-native, tabnavigator, react-native-tabnavigator

I want to disable swipe for tab change in TabNavigator.
I have found two solutions

1) `swipeEnabled: false,`

2) `navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false
    }`

both are not working in iOS in react-native.
Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: What react navigation version?

Comment: @Li357 used  ^2.8.0

Answer (score 0):

this works with "react-native": "^0.55.4" and has worked for a long time

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

const MyTabView = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        screen1: { screen: screen1 },
        screen2: { screen: screen2 },

      },
      {
        swipeEnabled: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: @Alainlb I want to use top tab bar so can't use bottomTabNavigator